# Perl HTTP Post Authentication

Tags: perl, http, authentication, post

Just wondering if anyone can see hwy this is not passing the username and password to the web server?

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->credentials("10.64.1.1:80", "realm-name", 'alexis','alexispass');
my $resp = $ua->post("http://10.64.1.1:80/CGI/Execute",
   { "Key" => "XML" , 
      "value" => "<setBackground><background><image>http://10.64.2.2/7945-65 NFullSize.png</image><icon>http://10.64.2.2/7945-65/NThumSize.png</icon></background></setBackground>"});
print $resp->content;
```

Thanks
alexis

Comment: What is the response?

Comment: Assuming it didn't (for you didn't show `$resp->request->as_string` to demonstrate that it didn't), it's presumably because the server did not return a 401 error requesting basic authentication to realm `realm-name`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I get an 401 Unauthorized

Comment: @ikegami Sorry i am not sure what exactly you mean. I think the issue is that when the server is asking for user name and password the script is not passing this info on. I relatively new to Perl and http. I am not confident in what "real-name" is an and how to use it..

Comment: Define what you mean by "the server is asking for user name and password"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this can help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
require LWP::UserAgent;
my $usr = 'alexis';
my $pass = 'alexispass';
my $URL = 'http://10.64.1.1:80/CGI/Execute';
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->timeout(20);
my $request = POST $URL,
                Content_Type    => [ 'Content_Type here' ],
                Content         => [ 'Content here' ];

$request->authorization_basic($usr, $pass);
my $response = $ua->request($request);
print $response->content;
```

This script use the POST() function from HTTP::Request::Common. If I understand correctly, that part of you POST-request should look like this:

```
my $request = POST $URL,
                   [ XML => '<setBackground><background><image>http://10.64.2.2/7945-65 NFullSize.png</image><icon>http://10.64.2.2/7945-65/NThumSize.png</icon></background></setBackground>'
                   ];
```

That request create object and it looks like this:

```
POST http://10.64.1.1:80/CGI/Execute
Content-Length: 66
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
XML=<setBackground><background><image>http://10.64.2.2/7945-65 NFullSize.png</image><icon>http://10.64.2.2/7945-65/NThumSize.png</icon></background></setBackground>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My apologies, I was sure I accepted this as an answer and thank you a while back. Your answer is what i was looking for. Thanks again. Alexis